# Spark streaming: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to start spark streaming in standalone mode (MacOSX) and getting the following error nomatter what:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>         at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.addShutdownHook(DiskBlockManager.scala:147)
>         at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.(DiskBlockManager.scala:54)
>         at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.(BlockManager.scala:75)
>         at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.(BlockManager.scala:173)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:347)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:194)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:450)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:566)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:578)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.(StreamingContext.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.(JavaStreamingContext.scala:78)
>         at io.ascolta.pcap.PcapOfflineReceiver.main(PcapOfflineReceiver.java:103)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
>         at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1584)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:220)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:189)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
>         ... 13 more

This symptom is discussed in relation to EC2 at https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2227/shutdown-hook-priority-javalangnosuchfieldexceptio.html as a Hadoop2 dependency. But I'm running locally (for now), and am using the spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz binary from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html which I'd hoped would eliminate this possibility.

I've pruned my code down to essentially nothing; like this:

> ```
> SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
>       .setAppName(appName)
>       .setMaster(master);
>   JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));
> ```

I've permuted maven dependencies to ensure all spark stuff is consistent at version 1.5.2. Yet the ssc initialization above fails nomatter what. So I thought it was time to ask for help.

Build environment is eclipse and maven with the shade plugin. Launch/run is from eclipse debugger, not spark-submit, for now.

Comment: Could you file a Spark JIRA ticket for this? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK

Comment: ...And when you do, please post the issue's URL here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this issue today, it is because I have two jars: hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar  and hadoop-core-1.6.1.jar in my pom，and they all dependency hadoop.fs.FileSystem.

but in FileSystem-1.6.1 there is no SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY Property in FileSystem Class. and FileSystem-2.7.2 has. but it seems that my code think FileSystem-1.6.1 is the right Class. So this issue raise.

the solution is also simple, delete hadoop-core-1.6.1 in pom. it means we need to check all FileSystem in our project is above 2.x.